# Positioning css-shaped triangle

Tags: css

I'm trying to place a css-shaped triangle inside a div.

Here is CSS:

```
/*Outer DIV*/

div.auth { 
display: block;
background: powderblue;
padding: 0.5rem;
margin-bottom: 1rem;
width: 90%;

/*Triangle DIV*/

div.arrow {
   width: 0.5em;
   height: 65%;
   background-color: #000;
   position: relative;} 

   div.arrow::after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -60%;
    transform: translateY(80%);
    bottom: -1em;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1em 1em 0 1em;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #000;
    }
```

Desired result:
[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/k1x1car4/

How can I can do the same placement in a less tricky and more precise manner?
Thank you!

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/k1x1car4/1/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are able to change `div.arrow`, but if so I recommend you not to use a pseudo-element at all and just put the triangle directly into `div.arrow`. You can then position it using

```
position: absolute
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

Note: You're going to have to add `position:relative` to `div.auth` in order for `position:absolute` to work on `div.arrow`.

```css
div.auth {
  display: block;
  background: powderblue;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  width: 90%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
  border-left: 3px solid #ccc;
  font-family: "T3";
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
}

div.arrow {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1em 1em 0 1em;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #000;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="auth">
  <div class="arrow"></div>par Makarios, Évêque de Lampsaque</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an `.arrow` class and a pseudo-element on the **parent** div.

There is **no need** to create *actual* HTML for styling in this intance.

Then position element `bottom:0` and `left:0`. Simple!

```css
div.auth {
  background: powderblue;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  width: 90%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
  border-left: 3px solid #ccc;
  font-family: "T3";
  text-align: right;
}

div.arrow {
  position: relative;
}

div.arrow::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1em 1em 0 1em;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="auth arrow">par Makarios, Évêque de Lampsaque</div>
```